# Apache NiFi - Generic Execution Flows?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm trying to figure out if the following scenarios are possible:

1. I have hundreds of tables that need to use the same flow, but have different intervals, different source hostnames and destinations?
   How to build such a flow?  also I can't figure out how to use dynamic hosts/schemas/table names...

We maintain a table with with all this info but how to execute it with NiFi?

2. If I need to load a file on multiple clusters (each table different clusters) in parallel - how can this be achieved?

tnx!

Comment: the one of the solutions: for each interval/schedule create FetchFile that loads json file with array of host/table/schema to be processed in this schedule. then use SplitJson to produce separate ff for each host/table/schema, then JsonToAttributes to put json values in attribute, then your main flow with parameters from flow files..

Comment: the load balancing between nodes could be managed in any queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to use an external schedular (like airflow)
and to use `ListenHttp` processor.
Then you can send to that listener any data you wish parse it and use it as parameters/attributes in the rest of the flow.